# prettier vs. nx format:check

Tags: prettier, nrwl

[nx format:check](https://nx.dev/web/api/workspace/npmscripts/format-check) expects no colon after `else` in html files:

```html
<div *ngIf="isValid; else errors">
```

but when I run prettier in the same project it expects a colon after `else`

```html
<div *ngIf="isValid; else: errors">
```

- why is this different?
  I thought that `nx format:check` just executes prettier in my root directory?
- Is there some config-option that I am missing?

**More info**:

In a subdirectory which includes an angular template, I can verify the issue:

```
$ nx format:check --files login.component.html

$ prettier -c login.component.html
Checking formatting...
login.component.html
Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?
```

Note, that nx does not report an issue, but prettier does: here are the versions:

```
$ nx --version
8.5.0
$ prettier --version
1.18.2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes that's right, `nx format:check` uses prettier under the hood.
However, the inconsistency that you are seeing here could be due to two different Prettier versions.

In my case, I was using [prettier-vscode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) which was using prettier version 1.8 which was different from the prettier version being used with nx lib.

There is a related issue for nx: [Feature Request: use installed prettier version](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1863)
The prettier version of nx can be found in their [package.json](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/package.json#L165)

Comment: I've updated the question with more info and the versions. I don't even use an IDE or plugin: just execute `nx` and `prettier` in the same directory to check the same file.

Comment: @TmTron  Exactly what I thought, So current version of nx (8.5) does not use latest prettier, instead it uses prettier version `1.16.4`, so I if you downgrade your prettier to be `1.16.4` until nrwl releases new version using prettier `1.18.2`.

I already did a PR for it and it is merged to master now but not released, You can watch it here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/1809.

Comment: so nx has some fixed prettier version that it is built with and does not just use the installed prettier version? Wo we must always make sure to keep the nx and prettier versions on our system in sync?

Comment: Kind of. I think there was already an issue about this, where the proposal was to make nx use prettier from project if there is one. But for now yes we will have to manually keep both prettier versions in sync.

Comment: I also thought that nx will just use the installed prettier version. Do you have a link to the proposal? Otherwise I'll file a new feature-request issue for nx. Maybe they can at least show a warning in that case or mention it in the docs.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not. Cann you please post a link here when you have filled new issue, so that anyone else that hits this issue can also track that issue on github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199673/discussion-between-rushi-patel-and-tmtron).

Comment: I've filed an issue for nx: [Feature Request: use installed prettier version](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1863)

Comment: This sort of issue is best avoided by not globally installing tools like prettier. You can easily use the locally installed version by running `npx prettier`, so you don't actually need the global one, even for manual use on the command line. You should install the dependency in every project where you use prettier anyway, so if it helps you could always add `alias prettier="npx prettier"`

Comment: @Thor84no in my case prettier was not installed globally - the issue was that the nx did not use the prettier version specified in `package.json`, but instead used it's own (hardcoded) version